# why this simple jquery code doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

I would like to start using jquery and I found this code in a tutorial I was following on youtube. In the comments I've seen that it doesn't work for a lot of users but there isn't a real fix.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
</head>
<body>
    <p onclick="$(this).hide();">this is a paragraph</p>
    <script source="js/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the folder of this page I created a subfolder called js where I saved the jquery.js file copying the code from jquery.com

Comment: Check your console, do you see any errors? (F12 on Chrome / IE)

Comment: You have to load jQuery _before_ you try to run jQuery code.

Comment: check if Jquery file is being loaded, also include it before you run script

Comment: yes in google chrome console I got the error

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: in the tutorial he says to put it always at the end of the page just before the closing tag </body>

Answer (score 1):

One step forward would be not to put code inline with markup...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
</head>
<body>
    <p>this is a paragraph</p>
    <script source="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() 
            $('p').on('click', function() {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use jQuery before jQuery has been included.

The `<script src='jquery.js'></script>` has to appear before you use `$` or `jQuery`. Typically, you'd include it in the `<head>` of your document.

You should also decouple your JavaScript from your DOM, by moving your event bindings into the `<head>` as well, and wrapping them in a `$(document).ready` block:

```
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('p').click(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: in the tutorial he says to write it at the end of the page, just before </body>

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. In google chrome console it says

"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined "

Comment: @Gabz Then jQuery isn't being included. You're presumably using the wrong URL, `js/jquery.js`.

Comment: it isn't the problem. I've now tried to put jquery.js now in the same folder of the page and refer src='jquery.js'

Comment: and it isn't a path problem also because if I try your code it works!

Comment: Wait, so, does or doesn't my solution work? You've said both now.

Comment: sorry, I meant your solution works so it isn't a problem of wrong url. There should be some mistake in the tutorial's code.

Comment: As I said, the tutorial is wrong: you cannot include jQuery at the bottom of the script, and use it at the top. You *must* include jQuery **before** you use `$`.

Comment: that's not true. I've tried it successfully with other examples.

Answer (score 0):

a best practice for javascript is to always load your dependencies in your `<head>`tag in order of dependency. in this case, you place your jQuery reference first, then any own files referring to jQuery.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <script source="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p onclick="$(this).hide();">this is a paragraph</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: This isn't a "best practice", it's a hard technical requirement. In fact, it's a best practice to put scripts at the bottom when possible. You *do* have to include the base-line dependencies for your scripts before you use them though.